# How to run a multifile program from github

Tags: python, github

After downloading a multi-file python program from github, which file do you call to run the entire program?

More specifically, I am trying to run the program listed [here](https://github.com/benhoff/vex)

Comment: In this case the authors of the code failed to add a `README.md`, but I bet you can go to the `src` folder and run the `__main__.py` script, since that has a `main` method.

Comment: I will at some point publish this to pypi with the appropriate entry point enabled so that this process will be as easy as `pip install vexbot`. Everything just needs a little more polish currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what environment you're running in (e.g. Windows, Linux), the details vary.  However what you want is to download the whole thing in the hierarchy it already has, navigate to the `src` directory and invoke python on the main program, which in this case seems to be `__main__.py`.

From a Linux or Mac OS X command line, you might do

```
git clone https://github.com/benhoff/vex
cd vex/src
python __main__.py
```

However it has some requirements listed in the `requirements.txt` file.  These have to be installed on your system for it to work.  Try `cd vex; pip install -r requirements.txt`. On my Mac OS X El Capitain, `pip` wasn't installed, but [instructions for that are available](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/#install-pip).

Comment: Thank you, i have the interpreter running on osx

Comment: So do I, so I've expanded the answer with more Mac OS X details.

Answer (score 0):

Download it as a zip (github provides a convenient link) and unpack? (or run from a zip: 
https://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2012/05/21/python-zip-files/ )

Comment: I have it downloaded and unzipped.